# Display the table of content on sidebar

Tags: css, hexo

I installed [theme-next/hexo-theme-next: Elegant and powerful theme for Hexo.](https://github.com/theme-next/hexo-theme-next) and configured `_config.yml` in themes/next dir

```
# Table Of Contents in the Sidebar
toc:
  enable: true
  # Automatically add list number to toc.
  number: true
  # If true, all words will placed on next lines if header width longer then sidebar width.
  wrap: false
  # If true, all level of TOC in a post will be displayed, rather than the activated part of it.
  expand_all: false
  # Maximum heading depth of generated toc. You can set it in one post through `toc_max_depth` in Front-matter.
  max_depth: 6

sidebar:
  # Sidebar Position, available values: left | right (only for Pisces | Gemini).
  position: left
  #position: right
```

Unfortunately, the  table of content  is  not displayed.

[image]

The result I want is :[Sidebar | NexT](https://theme-next.org/docs/theme-settings/sidebar)

[image]

What's the problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about your condition since there is no screenshot or url of the full page. But from the first screenshot, I guess you are in home page. You need to click into the page of blog to see the table of contents.

To be more specific, `www.home_page.com` will not show the `toc` while `www.home_page.com/blog` will show the `toc`.